# How can I secure JSON web service?

Tags: php, api, security

I have location data containing lat,long,location_name to be shown in the map. Only logged in users can see this map. What I did was that I used php and with a select * to MySQL DB and then I used json_encode to format the data in usable way and echoed it to be grabbed in the front-end and used in map api. This php file echoing the JSON file is called mapData.php
I want this file to not be accessible even from logged user. I came across session and request headers in the mapData.php file (internal api file)but then again if h hacker sign up to my service and open dev console he/she can see the received file and with one side requesting tool can put the header and see the data. Or maybe changing the access level with Linux but I have no idea how.
Another method is uglify and minifying JSON but since I am having 29000 rows in my dB with another inner join I think it will slow down the process. Any suggestion for securing this internal api so that even logged in user cannot access to it?

Comment: This isn't possible. If the data is being processed on the client side, the user can see it. Anything you don't want the user to see must be kept on the server.

Comment: Obfuscating it won't help. There has to be a function in your Javascript that decodes it, and the user can simply call that function himself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would hide the map data file in a subdirectory, then use a service to access the data file and retrieve just the data you need. If you absolutely need the 29,000 rows at once, then there's not much you can do. Even if you encrypt it, eventually the data is going to be in native JavaScript format, and then it's just a matter of running a debugger and peering in the data structures.

Comment: I don't think he's getting the data from a file, it's coming from a database, and PHP is sending it all to the client.

Comment: Yes, basically I think it is more dynamic to use internal API and use AJAX to request this file. What if I require_once the mapData.php file on top of map.phtml ? is this possible to somehow feed a PHP variable to js script? I mean I fetch data from MySQL encoded it in a JSON file and then some how give it to js file all in one file?

Comment: @Ali - not sure what your approach is. If you're sending all the data to the browser, doesn't matter what you do with it. If the browser decodes it, then it's going to be visible to the debugger.